# Statistics to shades in a world map

Tags: api, gis, geography

Is there any API or web service to create statistical world maps where the values are different shades of a colour?

Something like http://www.visualizingeconomics.com/wp-content/uploads/sachs-gdpdensity.png

Comment: i think this question should be either reasked or migrated to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use Google Fusion Tables (http://google.com/fusiontables) to upload your attribute data to.  If it's country (or county-based for example in the USA) you can visualize the data as an Intensity Map, or - if you have geometries for the data as well - as a more complex overlay on a Google Map.  Some examples at https://sites.google.com/site/fusiontablestalks/stories

Answer (score 1):

Any basic GIS software will do the trick if you have the proper geographic layers.

- [QGIS](http://qgis.org) would be a good and simple tool
- There are a lot of World GIS maps out there (the conventional format is usually .shp) .shp files are a group of 4 or more files with the same name but with different file extensions.
- You'll edit the data in QGIS and add your field either based on an equation or inputed data.

Answer (score 1):

Google Visualization API now includes geochart which is simple and easy.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery plugin [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net) for visualizing data of such kind. It is possible to color particular regions on map (world, USA and Germany maps are available now, some others will be available soon).